# The text property value does not change at runtime when using a style (MAUI)

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, label, maui

I have utilized a style for the label and bound its text property to a property in the ViewModel. Initially, I set the label's text value using the property in the ViewModel. Later, I changed its text property value by referencing it with a x:name in a button-clicked event. The text changed accordingly. and then, when I tried changing the binded property in the ViewModel using another button-clicked event, the text on the View did not update.

**github sample link** : https://github.com/RiyashameedM/Label_Text_issue

**MainPage.xaml**

```
 <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:ViewModel x:Name="vm" />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Label"
                   x:Key="CustomLabelStyle">
                <Setter Property="Text"
                        Value="{Binding SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay,Source={x:Reference vm}}"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <StackLayout x:Name="stack">
        <Button Text="set selected Item"
                Command="{Binding ListViewSelectionChangedCommand}"
                x:Name="btn"
                CommandParameter="{x:Reference label}"
                HeightRequest="50" />
        <Button Text="ChangeBinding"
                Clicked="Button_Clicked_1"
                x:Name="btn1" />
        <Label HeightRequest="50"
               Background="red"
               Style="{StaticResource CustomLabelStyle}"
               x:Name="label" />
    </StackLayout>
```

ViewModel.cs

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string selectedItem;

    public string SelectedItem
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set { selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
        }
    }
    public ICommand ListViewSelectionChangedCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        this.SelectedItem = "old value";
        ListViewSelectionChangedCommand = new Command(OnSelectionChanged);
    }

    private void OnSelectionChanged(object obj)
    {
        this.SelectedItem = "new value";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

Label should be rendered on view after changing its text using the property in Viewmodel which in bound to the Text Property in Style

Comment: If you want to use Style for the Text Property, don't explicitly set the value for it in code behind. Just like the first button, use data bindings to change the ```SelectedItem``` property.

Comment: If you set the Text property, then the style does not work.

Answer (score 0):

> Label should be rendered on view after changing its text using the property in Viewmodel which in bound to the Text Property in Style

It can't real-time change for `Style`:

```xml
<Label ...
       Style="{StaticResource CustomLabelStyle}"
       .../>
```

Directly using this can real-time change Text of Label:

```xml
<Label HeightRequest="50"
       Background="red"
       Text="{Binding SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}"
       x:Name="label"/>
```

Here is the [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EznMN.gif).